# Show Date but no Time in Menu Bar

Tags: macos, menu-bar, time

Is it possible to show only the date in the menu bar and *not* the clock. When I go to System Preferences > Date & Time, I can only remove both, but I'd like to keep the date and only hide the time.

I also tried to go to Language & Region and change the format in which the time is shown to *nothing* but that did not do the trick either; the menubar clock just jumped back to the standard setting instead of removing the time, as I hoped.

Alternatively, is there any kind of "menu bar widgets" for Mac? maybe i can remove the time & date from the menu bar and add some sort of third party app which is showing the date.

I'm running High Sierra 10.13.3 on a 2017 13-inch MacBook Pro

Comment: There are many calendar apps for OS X that reside in the menu bar and show only the date. I haven't tried them, but here's the first I found: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mini-calendar/id1088779979?mt=12

Comment: Thank you Mateusz - the one you linked is exactly what i wanted :)